# cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I had trouble communicating between two views. My objective was to add a new object to my `NSMutableArray`. Thank to the lovely folks at stackoverflow that was fixed. Now I have another issue.
Even though I'm able to add object to my `NSMutableArray`, the table is not updating itself to repopulate using the new data. Here is some code:

### FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{  
    IBOutlet UITableView *mytableview;  
    NSMutableArray *mytableinfo;  
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *mytableview;  
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *mytableinfo;`
```

### FirstViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)addShift:(id)sender{
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [mytableinfo count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text =[mytableinfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Data was written to table");
    return cell;
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    mytableinfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    mytableview = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    [mytableinfo addObject:@"Hello world1"];
    [self.mytableview reloadData];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addShift:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;    
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    UIBarButtonItem *refresh = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(reloadTableData:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refresh;
    mytableinfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [mytableinfo addObject:@"First Shift"];
    [self.mytableview reloadData];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

### SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

-(IBAction)saveShift:(id)sender{
    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
    firstViewController.mytableinfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [firstViewController.mytableinfo addObject:@"SecondViwController Dismissed"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[firstViewController.mytableinfo objectAtIndex:0]);
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

So when `saveShift` is called I should be taken back to main view - which I do- and then repopulate my `tableview`. It's like I'm getting out of a small problem only to jump into another - not a really good feeling!
Cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `saveShift:(id)sender` method you have to much code.
Just do the following :

```
[self.myTableInfo addObject:@"SecondViewConroller dimissed"];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

In that code I'm assuming that you've passed a reference to your NSMutableArray in your secondView.

I remember your post from the NSMutableArray and you are presenting the SecondView from a FirstView (if my memory is good).
But in your code, in the `saveShift` of the secondView, you are presently creating a `brand new` FirstView, that is not the same from where you came from. So when you dismiss the modal view your "brand new" firstView get lost and you get back to your original firstView. And that last one haven't hear of your object.

---

Hi Sam,
go look at the last answer I've given you in your NSMutableArray thread, there is almost everything you need to solve this there.

---

OK, here is more of the quick fix so that could work

```
//  SecondViewController.m
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize dateformatter,mydatepicker,startingTime;
//  HERE Add a new property that match this and a variable in the .h
@synthesize array4Test;
//   HERE make an init that will make this UIViewController know about your NSMutableArray
- (id)initWithMutableArray:aMutableArray
{
self = [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
if (self)
{
    self.array4Test = aMutableArray;
}
return  self;
}
- (void)dealloc 
{    
//  HERE clean up
self.array4Test = nil;
[super dealloc];
}
-(IBAction)saveShift:(id)sender{
//    HERE remove this code
//FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
//[firstViewController.mytableinfo addObject:@"Hello world"];
//NSLog(@"%@",[firstViewController.mytableinfo objectAtIndex:0]);
//    HERE add an object to the mutableArray that is store in your firstViewController, the one you've passed the reference in
[self.array4Test addObject:@"This is a String"];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I think I've just added an NSLog() in this one.

```
//  FirstViewController.m
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize mytableinfo,mytableview;
@synthesize goneToOtherView;
-(IBAction)addShift:(id)sender{
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithMutableArray:self.mytableinfo];
[self presentModalViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.mytableview reloadData];
NSString *aString = [mytableinfo lastObject];
if (aString)
{
    NSLog(@"This just came back from the second View\n%@", aString);
}
}
```

Comment: OK!! I tried the code that was suggested above but I think I'm missing something out because it is not working. Your answer from the NSMutableArray helped me fixed that issue and I did try following the rest of that but I wasn't sure what goes where. As you can tell I'm brand new... not only to iOS but to programming.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least a couple of problems here.

First problem: you're creating an entirely new `FirstViewController` in `saveShift:`, instead of adding an object to the existing `FirstViewController`.  That's not going to work.  In `addShift:`, when you create `secondViewController`, you should pass the existing `FirstViewController` as a parameter, like this:

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithFirstViewController:self];
```

You'll need to modify `SecondViewController` to have an `initWithFirstViewController:` method which should store the `FirstViewController` in a property named `firstViewController`.

Second problem: you're not telling the table view about the new row.  You should add a method to `FirstViewController`:

```
- (void)reallyAddShift:(NSString *)newShift
{
    [self.mytableinfo addObject:newShift];
    NSIndexPath ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.mytableinfo count]-1 inSection:0];
    [self.mytableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ip] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Then, in `saveShift:`, you can just do this:

```
-(IBAction)saveShift:(id)sender{
    [self.firstViewController reallyAddShift:@"SecondViwController Dismissed"];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I'm really sorry to sound this stupid. When I put in the line `SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithFirstViewController:self];
`, the `initWithFirstViewController:self];` is underline with red in Xcode 4 and the error says **instance method '-initWithFirstViewController' not found. (return type defaults to 'id').** Any thoughts. What am I missing?

Comment: As I said in my answer: You'll need to modify SecondViewController to have an initWithFirstViewController: method which should store the FirstViewController in a property named firstViewController.

Comment: rob, I'm not sure how to this: **You'll need to modify SecondViewController to have an initWithFirstViewController: method which should store the FirstViewController in a property named firstViewController.** Can you please give me sample code of what I'll need to put in my second and first view controllers. Not to sure what a method is. Cheers

Comment: @sam look in the code I've put for this method : `- (id)initWithMutableArray:aMutableArray`  It's the same principle, but instead of passing the FirstView, in that exemple I'm only passing the NSMutableArray instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning simply `mytableinfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` will not retain it. Make that `self.mytableinfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`.

Comment: I tried that but no luck. But it's good to know what that extra `self` does. I used it a few times but never knew what it was for. Thanks.